# Unable to connect Zookeeper in gke cluster

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm, apache-zookeeper, vmware, bitnami

I am getting the below error while deploying the Apache Zookeeper bitnami charts
[Unable to connect Zookeeper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TsPkP.jpg)

**To connect to your ZooKeeper server run the following commands:**

```
export POD_NAME=$(kubectl get pods --namespace default -l "app.kubernetes.io/name=zookeeper,app.kubernetes.io/instance=zookeeper,app.kubernetes.io/component=zookeeper" -o jsonpath="{.items[0].metadata.name}")
kubectl exec -it $POD_NAME -- zkCli.sh
```

**error**:

```
error: error executing jsonpath "{.items[0].metadata.name}": Error executing template: array index out of bounds: index 0, length 0. Printing more information for debugging the template:
        template was:
                {.items[0].metadata.name}
        object given to jsonpath engine was:
                map[string]interface {}{"apiVersion":"v1", "items":[]interface {}{}, "kind":"List", "metadata":map[string]interface {}{"resourceVersion":"", "selfLink":""}}
```

error: pod, type/name or --filename must be specified

Answer (score 0):

Try running this command you will go inside the POD and further will be able to run that **zkCli.sh** file

```
kubectl exec -it zookeeper-0 -- /bin/bash
```

or

```
kubectl exec -it zookeeper-0 -- /bin/sh
```

Or you can also try once

```
kubectl exec -it zookeeper-0 -- zkCli.sh
```

Comment: I tried all, but No Result.
kubectl exec -it zookeeper-0 -- zkCli.sh this command runs internal with auth failed, but no use of running internal